# How requirejs handle jquery?

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I am reading some code which use requirejs to handle jquery.

It use

```
require([
'jquery',
], 

function(
$
){} );
```

I am wondering why just using $ is enough for all jquery functions?

Comment: Huh? What don't you understand? What would you expect?

Comment: You might be misunderstand that `$` has lots of properties.

Comment: I am wondering jquery support Requrejs by default? Requirejs needs every module use define.

Comment: I think you are using require-jquery.js which has already defined jquery.

Comment: if you are using https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery, take into account that is no longer recommended or mantained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will define `jquery` module by itself if `define` function has already defined.

The following code is in jquery.js.

```
if ( typeof module === "object" && module && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
    // Expose jQuery as module.exports in loaders that implement the Node
    // module pattern (including browserify). Do not create the global, since
    // the user will be storing it themselves locally, and globals are frowned
    // upon in the Node module world.
    module.exports = jQuery;
} else {
    // Otherwise expose jQuery to the global object as usual
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;

    // Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
    // files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
    // understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
    // way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
    // derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
    // file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
    // to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.
    if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
        define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [How to use RequireJS with jQuery](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html).

But yes, you only need `$` (witch is the same as `jQuery`) because every method (or plugin) jQuery provides is encapsulated inside that variable.

If you are using `requirejs` to load your files and you don't do it that way, `$` will be undefined.

Example from the site:

```
require(['jquery'], function( $ ) {
    console.log( $ ) // OK
});

require(['jquery'], function( jq ) {
    console.log( jq ) // OK
});

require(['jquery'], function( ) {
    console.log( $ ) // UNDEFINED!
});
```